# SQL Server Express database replication/synchronization

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

**Situation:**
Hi, I'm coding using Lightswitch (C#) and am thinking of deploying to multiple sites the same application and database.

The databases need to be synchronized/replicated to each other so each would have a merged database. However connectivity between the sites is not going to be 100%, so the synchronization/replication would be done whenever the connection is possible.

**Question:**

Would it be possible to accomplish this through SQL Server Express? If not, what would be the best way to accomplish this by code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Express doesn't support replication (except as a subscriber, as Davide pointed out).  I think your best bet would probably be a windows service that keeps track of table names and the most recent timestamp processed.

Integration Services is also an option if you have a server to run it on.

Do you need data to be moving one-way or both ways?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'll need to have a look on Integration Services. Data needs to be moving both ways. i.e. Site A, should also have Site B's data, and vice-versa.

Comment: thanks for mentioning Integration services, however it seems that this does not come with Express. http://www.sqlis.com/post/SQL-Server-Editions-and-Integration-Services.aspx

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a single database for both applications?  I'm not terribly familiar with lightswitch but it seems it should be an option.

Comment: You could treat Lightswitch as a Silverlight app. The reason why it has to be a multiple databases, is because the same application needs to be used on different physical locations. Then there's a need for Location A to see the data inputted in Location B, then vice-versa. Which brings me to thinking how to do synchronization of data.

Comment: If they can't connect to the same database, I would definitely look into upgrading to SQL Server standard (or using something like postgresql w/ RubyRep if money is an object)

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server Express 2008 can be a subscriber but not a publisher, see details here:

[Replication Considerations (SQL Server Express)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686.aspx)

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express (SQL Server Express) can serve as a
>   Subscriber for all types of replication, providing a convenient way to
>   distribute data to client applications that use SQL Server Express.
>   When using SQL Server Express in a replication topology, consider the
>   following:
>
> SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Publisher or Distributor.

Comment: however with that, what would you think the best way would be? Would this be feasible to accomplish through code?

Comment: if this is a commercial application you are building I would upgrade to SQL Server Standard. I would not even try to do replication via code...